# Poor performance on looping but quick on sequential executions

Tags: java, performance, exception

Assume my code is as follows:

```
int value=-1;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
f(value);
}
```

where `f` is a complex function which calls other classes..etc.

I have a performance issue here which makes the IDE (NetBeans) freezes and few minutes later throws a heap size exception. Actually it freezes even for two iterations (i<2)

However, when I sequentially execute

```
 f(value);
```

I got the answer right away with no exceptions.

How can I overcome such issue? is there any tweak/another way to run `f(value)` several times?

Comment: Are you sure the call in the cycle should not be `f(i)`? Why the cycle?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yes because I am doing some benchmarks (taking the average running time for a fixed parameter value).

Comment: so do you have any persistent values in your functtion f() which might be residing in the memory in succcessive iterations ?

Comment: Benchmarking like this will almost never make sense. Any reasonable compiler with optimizations turned on will only compute the value of the function once.

Comment: Make sure you are not changing the value of the variable `i` inside the loop.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev each call to 'f' has another random inputs (in addition to the parameter 'value')

Comment: You probably have error inside the loop or in `f(value)` code. If you want us to help, please include the **full** relevant code.

Comment: @whoAmI Thanks.. I will look into a way for this. It is 40+ classes related to this function call.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or simply adding some printouts to the code? This should help you identify the place where it starts to go wrong.

Comment: Did I understand your question right? When you "sequentially execute" `f`, do you execute it just once, or many times, like `f(...); f(...); f(...);`?

Comment: @tobias_k your elegant easy suggestion solves it! I never thought it will be that simple. The problem occurred because of a static variable 'var' inside 'f'. I forgot to initialize it to empty in each iteration. This makes it sum up all previous iterations' values to its current value and loop forever.. Thanks

Comment: @seteropere Um -- not sure what exactly I did, but glad I could help anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to review your code and related classes of the function `f(value);`. As you said, calling it one time is everything correct but for subsequent calls, you are facing heap memory exception. Make the unwanted object eligible for garbage collection, avoid string concatenation, some more tricks to utilize available memory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to execute the logic of `function f` ten times with the same input.
So it will be better to execute it within the function logic rather then calling function f ten times. It will `reduce the cost of function call ten times`.

(Not sure whether it will serve your purpose. Just try it.)

Comment: Will this cause an overhead of "several minutes" and cause a heap size exception?

Comment: definitely overhead will be reduced. heap size exception- i dont think so. But it is better of trying

Comment: I actually generate random inputs for f in each iteration while fixing only the value.

Comment: The overhead you want to save is rather negligible.